Loosing names for x values on x-axis in parallel sets chart with ggforce in R
According to this example: https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/geom_parallel_sets.html
This code
library(ggforce)
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)
data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4)

ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = 'white')

should return  
(note the names on the x-axis)
But when I run the same code I get: 
I.e., the names on the x-axis is not present. Anyone has a fix for this?

Looks like a bug to me. The issue is that the column names get dropped inside gather_set_data. Not sure whether this is due to a change in ggforce or one of the dependencies.
A possible workaround would be to manually re-label the x column like so:
Note: The issue was already reported on GH and there is already a (partial) fix in the dev version. IMHO only partial as it does not preserve the order of the columns.
library(ggforce)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

data <- reshape2::melt(Titanic)

data <- gather_set_data(data, 1:4) |> 
  transform(x = factor(x, labels = names(data)[1:4]))

ggplot(data, aes(x, id = id, split = y, value = value)) +
  geom_parallel_sets(aes(fill = Sex), alpha = 0.3, axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_axes(axis.width = 0.1) +
  geom_parallel_sets_labels(colour = "white")



Thanks!
Another solution I found was to add a manual scale in ggplot, like:
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,2,3,4),labels=c("Class", "Sex", "Age", "Survived")

A work-around I found was to specify the labels of your continuous scale in ggplot, like:
+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4,labels = c("Class", "Sex", "Age", "Survived")`

But the solution suggested by @stefan is more elegant.
